# How do I conditionally format a cell based on different cell results?

Tags: conditional-formatting, cell-format

[image]

I am making a spreadsheet that reads barcodes to scan an item in or out. I have  used VB to do this every time I scan a barcode so it adds a date and time horizontally across one row each time the barcode is scanned so alternate cells are headed as 'in' and 'out' then reads a time and date.

What I am looking to do is to format the cell that contains the barcode to highlight green if the item is in and red if the item is out. This would then be a quick reference when looking down the sheet of all items.

Is there a way to do this?! My excel skills aren't very strong so struggling a bit now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be helpful for you to have a column that clearly states "Out" or "In" based on the number of scans. The code can be placed in a new column for each row and should let you know this information. Note that I am assuming that an odd number of scans indicates the "Out" status and even number of scans represents the "In" status.

Add this to a new column:

```
=IF(MOD(COUNTA($B2:$ZZ2),2)=0,"In", "Out")
```

Where B is the first column of time stamps and ZZ is the farthest you can imagine scans going out.

COUNTA() counts the number of non-blank cells.
MOD() performs the modulo operator which indicates the remainder after division.
IF() sets a value based on a true or false result of a test.

From there you can use use conditional formatting to color the "IN/OUT" column as the appropriate color based on its own value.

**If you cannot add a column** since the VBA code would need to be changed and that is not acceptable then you can just use this formula in place of the formula I gave you below for your conditional formatting:

```
=MOD(COUNTA(C1:ZZ1),2)>0
```

This formula will check to see if the item is out. Use this formula to check for it being in:

```
=MOD(COUNTA(C1:ZZ1),2)<1
```

---

I think this is a great use of conditional formatting!

Start off by selecting the barcode column and going to conditional formatting at the ribbon on the top.

Select "New Rule"

Choose the last option in the Rule Type list: "Use a formula to determine which cells to format."

In the formula bar use this code type this

```
=ISNUMBER(FIND("Out",$A2))
```

Where A2 represents where the In/Out column is. Note that the dollar sign keeps the A column but adjusts the rule for each row down.

Now choose the formatting you want (i.e. the color background for the barcode cell).

You will then repeat these steps for formatting with a green background when the item is "In."

Edit:
Just for information sake, the FIND() function attempts to find the given text in a specified location. If it finds the text you are looking for then it returns the place in the string where the text started, otherwise it returns an error. Then we can use ISNUMBER() to check whether the returned value was a number and, therefore, was located in the specified cell.

Comment: Hi Joey,
Thanks for your help, however the cells don't say In or Out, they just have a time stamp and then it posts to the next cell when scanned again so I end up with a row of time stamps - I'm not sure how to make it say in or out as I copied the VB code from a forum! Is there a way to still do the formatting on a time stamp?

Comment: Would you be able to edit your original post with an example? If I understand it correctly, your row will continually grow in length every time the item is scanned. Is this correct? If so, is it fair to say that if there are an odd number of time stamps then it is checked out and an even number means checked in?

Comment: I've added a screenshot to my original post. Yes, I would have a continually growing line depending on the amount of times the barcode is scanned. Sorry, It's a bit hard to explain!

Comment: I understand. Give me a moment to edit my answer.

Comment: That's worked a charm! I managed to modify the VB so went with your first formula. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: No problem. Have a great day!